# Java Compiler Incorrect Boxed Primitive Coercion

Tags: java, javacompiler

USING: `openjdk-11-jdk-headless=11.0.16+8-0ubuntu1~20.04`

I have `ClassB` with a `static` creation method in a library.

```
public ClassB
{
  public static ClassB create(UUID id, boolean flag);
}
```

In another library I have `ClassA` calling the creation method like this:

```
// Note that "false" is passed in as a literal.
return ClassB.create(someId, false);
```

I get `NoSuchMethodError` and it reports the signature called as `(java.util.UUID, java.lang.Boolean)`.

When I decompile the `ClassA.class` file it gives me this:

```
// With CFR
ClassB getInputs(UUID id) {
  return ClassB.create((UUID)id, (Boolean)false);
}

// With Procyon
ClassB getInputs(final UUID id) {
  return ClassB.create(id, Boolean.valueOf(false));
}
```

Both decompilers show that, when compiled, my method call ends up coercing the primitive `boolean` literal that I pass in to a boxed `Boolean` which makes all my calls blow up at runtime.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

**NOTE:**
I have confirmed that I can fix this by declaring a variable:
`private static final boolean FLAG = false;`
but I want to understand why this is happening.

Comment: please include a [mre] in question (posted code works for me, after adding missing parts)

Comment: It also works for me depending on where I build the project.
I believe its some difference in compilers OR environment.
I can make it work; what I'm really looking for is an explanation of why a Java compiler might choose to output bytecode that does this.

Comment: Are you using different versions of `ClassB` during compile time and runtime? Compare your runtime classpath against your compile classpath configuration. (You can get the runtime classpath with `System.getProperty("java.class.path")`.)

Comment: Good question.  No we are using Gradle to pull from a maven repo in Artifactory.
The jars/versions etc should be consistent.
Also, looking at the git commit history, the method call has never passed in boxed boolean.

Comment: Are you using any bytecode rewriting things like Lombok or annotation processors?

Comment: No bytecode rewriting processors are being used.